# Google Play Books enhanced with video not working

Tags: ebook-readers, epub, indesign, google-play-books

I am developing an enhanced ebook for Google Play Books in fixed layout epub. I am using Adobe **Indesign** to develop this ebook. I am having great difficulty adding videos in my ebook. I have exhausted all possible options to embed the video. I have tried `HTML5 video` tag as suggested by the [official Google support](https://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3316879?hl=en-GB). I have tried to embed youtube video using an `iframe` but no luck.

When I upload my ebook to **GPB** it doesn't display any video in case of HTML5 and in case of iframes `iframe` takes some real estate but shows up blank. The iframe however does show on web version of the app and videos stream alright.

How can I embed videos successfully in my ebook? either `HTML5` or `iframe` will do for me.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code, preferably the HTML 5 version? Also, what video format and codec are you using?

Comment: I am following official doc. [link](https://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3316879?hl=en-GB)